# How do you solve the diference quotient for $f(x) = 23 \sqrt{x}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do I solve the difference quotient for $f(x) = 23 \sqrt{x}$? I know how to plug it in but I don't understand how to simplify.

Comment: It's is entirely unclear what you mean by 23squareRoot. Do you mean $$23\sqrt{x}$$ or $$\sqrt[23]{x}$$ or something else.

Comment: I mean the first one.

Comment: The correct answer should be 23 divided by the square root of x + h times the square root of x. Please help me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** rationalize the numerator
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} &=
\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{23\sqrt{x+h}-23\sqrt{x}}{h} \\
&=
\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{23\sqrt{x+h}-23\sqrt{x}}{h} \cdot 
\frac{\sqrt{x+h}+\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x+h}+\sqrt{x}} \\
&= 
\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{23(x+h)-23x}{h(\sqrt{x+h}+\sqrt{x})}\\
&= 
\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{23h}{h(\sqrt{x+h}+\sqrt{x})}
\end{align}
$$

Where can we go from here?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough. I know that I have to rationalize the numerator and I got to the step where you are. I just can't algebraically simplify it from there.

Comment: @Anon, the algebraic step just comes from the fact that $(a-b)(a+b) = a^2 - ba + ab - b^2 = a^2 - b^2$, since real numbers commute. Just be cautioned that in some fields $AB \neq BA$.

Comment: @Anon I've updated my answer simplified it a bit for you. Can you take it from there?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom THANK YOU SO MUCH! That's exactly what I was looking for! I forgot to put the parantheseesaround the X+H when I was multiplying by the conjugate. THANK YOU!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

For some $\Delta x$ the difference quotient will be:

$$\frac{\Delta F(x)}{\Delta x} = \frac{23 (\sqrt{x + \Delta x} - \sqrt{x})}{\Delta x}.$$

The difference quotient becomes the derivative when you take the limit as $\Delta x$ approaches zero.  Otherwise, this is your answer (a divided difference), and whether or not you can simplify it further depends on your chosen values of $x$ and $\Delta x$.

Comment: You need the 23 on both square roots.

Comment: Yeah, just saw that.  Thanks.

Comment: I'm still in pre calc and we're learning this without the whole limit delta stuff. I just need to know how to simplify what Omonomomom wrote in his post.

Answer (score 0):

I actually had to look up the definition for "difference quotient". I had never heard this term before... and I am well past the stage where it's relevant. Basically fancy words for taking derivatives:

$$\text{lim} \frac{23\sqrt{x+h}-23\sqrt{x}}{h} = 23\cdot \text{lim} \frac{h}{h\cdot(\sqrt{x+h}+\sqrt{x})} = 23/(2\sqrt{x})$$

Indeed, for $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$, $Df(a) = 1/2\cdot a^{-1/2}$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{matrix}
\frac{{\rm d} f(x)}{{\rm d}x}
&=& \lim_{h\to0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}\\
&=& 23 \lim_{h\to0} \frac{\sqrt{x+h}-\sqrt{x}}{h}\\
&=& 23 \lim_{h\to0} \frac{h}{h(\sqrt{x+h}+\sqrt{x})}\\
&=& 23 \lim_{h\to0} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x+h}+\sqrt{x}}\\
&=& \frac{23}{2\sqrt{x}}\\
\end{matrix}$$